# Intergrate website to Microsoft Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: browser, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

How can I integrate a website or a web browser to Microsoft outlook 2007/2010? The website should appear inside the Outlook just like an Outlook application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your website URL to one of the folders of your outlook. 
You can also do it with outlook add-in . So that you can assign webviewURL of folders through code.